# What is a "sounds like" thesaurus called?

Tags: dictionaries, phonology, rhymes

A dictionary contains word definitions.

A thesaurus contains words that mean the same (synonyms).

I'm looking for a name for a word dictionary that will give you *rhymes* (or "sounds like") of a word.

For example:  rhyme -> crime, prime

or, "rhyme" with "lunchtime".

What is this called and are there dictionaries or software or databases that contain these linkages?  I'm aware (for computer programmers) there is an ability in MySQL to run a [sounds like](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like) query.

Comment: A rhyming dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, but “rhyme” does *not* with “lunchtime” rhyme. Wrong stress.

Answer (score 7):

Like Mitch says, you're probably looking for a *Rhyming Dictionary*.

You can find many Rhyming Dictionaries over the internet. [Rhyme Zone](http://www.rhymezone.com/?loc=bar) is a particularly good one, since it groups results into syllables, which can be helpful for poetry writing or any similar activity.

A google search of Rhyming Dictionary software could get you something useful, although most of the software I found cost money, so you may have a bit of trouble there.

Comment: Yes, that’s the one I always use; I like it a lot. But is “RD” software research and development, or rhyming dictionaries, or what?  I think you should not use an abbreviation like that in your answer; it’s confusing.

Comment: Oh, my apologies. RD stands for "Rhyming Dictionary."

Answer (score 1):

I will offer a slightly more Information Technology-based answer.

SOUNDEX:Soundex is a phonetic algorithm for indexing names by sound, as pronounced in English. The goal is for homophones to be encoded to the same representation so that they can be matched despite minor differences in spelling.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

dictionary here:

http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/soundex_match.php

Answer (score 0):

It is called a homophone and there are homophone dictionaries. You can go to a rhyming dictionary and choose  homophone in the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

An International Thesaurus contains words that have similar meanings after the original format of Roget where you look up words in the alphabetical index to find groups of words with similar meanings.

Most common today are dictionary thesaurus that let you look up specific words but have limited ability to find new words.

A rhyming dictionary lets you look up words based on vowel sounds and consonants that follow the vowel.

I'm not sure what type you need?